# Inject values into a CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I apologize in advance if this question has been asked before.  I tried searching as best I could but I don't really know how to describe it.

I'm adding comments to a table of data.  I would like the background of the comment bubble to be a different colour based on the user.  The comment bubbles use CSS classes with the background embedded.  See below

```
.triangle-border {
  position:relative;
  padding:5px;
  margin:1em 0 3em;
  border:1px solid #CECECF;
  color:#333;
  background:#f8f4d4;   /* <<== background here */
  /* css3 */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5a8f00 transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-border.left:before {
  top: 5px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:-20px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width: 0px 20px 10px 0;
  border-color:transparent #CECECF;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border.left:after {
  top:6px; /* value = (:before top) + (:before border-top) - (:after border-top) */
  bottom:auto;
  left:-15px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:0px 16px 7px 0;
  border-color:transparent #f8f4d4; /* <<== and here */
}
```

I then use Razor to create the comment bubble in code:

```
<div style="height: 30px;">
    @comment.User
    <span class="triangle-border left" style="width: @comment.CommentLength">@comment.Text</span>
    <span style="font-size: 12px">@comment.CreateDate</span>
</div>
```

What I was planning on doing is storing a couple dozen or so different background colours in a table and assigning users to a unused colour when they log in.  Afterwards the comments for that user would appear in their assigned colour.  At first I thought I would have to create a whole bunch of classes with different colours (I may have to do this anyway).  But I was hoping there would be a more dynamic way I could do this.  If I could somehow inject the colour into the css without altering everyone else's comments that would be great.

I'm thinking another less desirable way would be to have all the styles inline and I could use razor to inject the background colour.  The problem with this is I may have a couple hundred comments on a page and this would make the page quite big and possibly slow to render.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  If you need clarification or more code on my problem don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You would normally inject inline styles on elements and not change the CSS.

Comment: Also, a suggestion. We recently found an algorithm to generate "nice" colours based on a hash of some string (e.g. your usernames). That would give a very consistent experience. I will dig it out.

Comment: You don't need all the styles to be inline, you just overwrite the color inline. Is that what you think will make it too long?

Comment: Please do not inject inline styles. It makes it a pain to maintain. Instead add and remove classes.

Comment: @ sareed: Color is one style you *would* normally use inline in this situation. Obviously not the rest of the styles.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Even then from a practice standpoint it is better to go with a color class. Say later on the OP or another developer needs to add a moderator class that has a special color signifying the status. The inline color styling would interfere. Inline styles like inline JS should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @sareed: You are arguing for the exact opposite of what I am suggesting below (dynamic colours based on content). Groups colours, based on classes, do not make sense for *unique* users (which is what they want to color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tasks are suited to client-side code. This appears to be one of them as you want a variety of values, per element, rather than sets of elements (which is better suited to class styling in CSS).

The following code, which I have rewritten as a jQuery extension, will generate a color to be used as the background based on the hash value of the text in the specified element. Simply use `.hashColor()` on the required elements.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/040yL80p/1/

```
$.fn.hashColor = function (options)
    {
        // Merge options into an empty object
        options = $.extend({}, options);
        this.each(function ()
        {
            var $this = $(this);

            // Get the source of the text to hash
            var str = options.textSelector ? $this.find(options.textSelector).text() : $this.text();

            // Find the target for the background color and class
            var $target = options.bgSelector ? $this.find(options.bgSelector) : $this;

            var hash = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            {
                hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
            }
            var colour = '#';
            var rgb = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
                rgb[i] = value;
                colour += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
            }

            var lum = Math.sqrt(rgb[0] * rgb[0] * .299 + rgb[1] * rgb[1] * .587 + rgb[2] * rgb[2] * .114);

            $target.css('background-color', colour);
            $target.toggleClass('Light', lum < 100);
        });
        return this;
    }
```

Test code

```
$('.comment .username').hashColor();
```

**Notes:**

- It automatically adds the class `.Light` when the value appears to be too dark for dark text. This allows for contrasting text.
- The `textSelector` option allows you to target parent elements instead for the color, but get the text from descendants using a relative selector.
- The `bgSelector` option allows you to target a descendant within the matched elements for the colour changes.

e.g.

```
 $('.comment').hashColor({textSelector: '.username'});
```

results in coloring the entire comment, based on a child element: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/040yL80p/2/

Comment: This is even better since I wouldn't have to store a list of colours somewhere for use with future users.

Comment: @Zoey: That's the idea. We started using it at work for a list of client names and it worked really well.

Comment: I played with it in Fiddler and the usernames themselves have a background colour.  I was aiming to change the comment bubbles background colour.  Hopefully this link works: http://jsfiddle.net/f1xbp397/
The reason this is difficult to figure out is that I have to change the background of the bubble as well as the little triangle.  I indicated the spots in my original post ("<<== background here" and "<<== and here").  This is why I was thinking that the hard solutions would be to hardcode styles for a bunch of colours or have them inline. I'll play some more and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Zoey: Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f1xbp397/1/ ? I added the two selectors specifically to cater for other targets within the selected elements (both for the text and for the color change).